# How can I get the anchor (#tag) from an <a> link in tritium?

Tags: moovweb

I am trying to get the anchor tag from an anchor element link in the page eg

```
<a href="/page#reviews">
```

Is it possible to access the href so I can isolate #reviews and use it elsewhere in my Tritum script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, using a two step process.

First, you can grab the value of the `href` attribute using the [`fetch()`](http://tritium.io/simple-mobile/1.0.118#Node.fetch%28Text%20%25selector%29%20Text%20Text) function.

Then, working on the isolated string, you can use regular expressions to replace all the characters that occur in front of the hash/pound sign (`#`) with a blank.

Here's an example using the Tritium Tester: http://tester.tritium.io/52503bcbe166ca7affa4944d90aae39808c8cd8e.

**Note**: This assumes that everything after the first `#` sign in the `href` attribute is what you're looking for.